# Simple gradle dagger java example

Tags: java, gradle, dagger

I have prepared simple gradle demo project example where dagger 2.2 is used. Demo is on [https://github.com/klaun76/gradle-dagger-java-simple-example)](https://github.com/klaun76/gradle-dagger-java-simple-example).

But when i changed version to 2.3 i got error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSetMultimap$Builder.putAll(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap$Builder;
```

I'm probably missing some dependencies. Any advice could help

Answer (score 0):

Its working now. Problem was in dependencies order, check latest version of [repository](https://github.com/klaun76/gradle-dagger-java-simple-example)